# How to write mysql query in codeigniter Active Record form?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to write bellow mysql query in form of codeigniter Active Record

```
select c.*
from code c
left join code_like l on c.id = l.code_id
group by c.id
order by count(*) desc
```

I am try bellow query but how to add `order by count(*) desc`

```
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('code');
        $this->db->join('code_like', 'code.id = code_like.id');
        $this->db->group_by("code.id"); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work for you, as you have typos within your code

```
$this->db->select('c.*,count(c.*) as data');
$this->db->from('code c');
$this->db->join('code_like cl', 'c.id = cl.code_id','left');
$this->db->group_by('c.id');
$this->db->order_by('data DESC');
$result = $this->db->get->result_array();
print_r($result);
```